# Extension of continuous function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,\tau), (Y,\upsilon)$ be topological spaces, $(S,\tau_S)$ be a closed subspace of $(X,\tau)$ equipped with subspace topology, and $f:S \to Y$ be a $(\tau_S,\upsilon)$-continuous function.

> Statement:
>
> If $f\restriction_{\partial S} = y$, the extension $\phi:X \to Y, \phi\restriction_S = f, \phi\restriction_{S^c} = y$ is $(\tau,\upsilon)$-continuous.

Is this statement true or false? If it is false, what is the minimal requirement on $(Y,\upsilon)$ for it to be true?

Attempt 1:

Let $V \in \upsilon$. We wish to show that for every such $V$, $\phi^{-1}[V] \in \tau$. If $y \not\in V$, then $\phi^{-1}[V] = f^{-1}[V] \in \tau_S$, so there exists $U \in \tau$ such that $\phi^{-1}[V] = U \cap S$. Since $\phi^{-1}[V]$ cannot intersect $\partial S$, $\phi^{-1}[V] \subseteq S^\circ$, and the intersection $\phi^{-1}[V] = S^\circ \cap V$ is open.

If $y \in V$, then also $f^{-1}[V] \in \tau_S$ and $\phi^{-1}[V] = f^{-1}[V] \cup S^c$, but $f^{-1}[V]$ is often open in $\tau$. How should I proceed here?

Attempt 2: Let $\langle x_j \rangle_{j \in M}$ be a net in $X$ converging to $x \in X$. We wish to show that for every neighbourhood $V \ni y$, $\langle f(x_j) \rangle_{j \in M}$ is eventually in $V$. If $x \in S^\circ$ or $x \in S^c$, then this statement is trivially satisfied, so let $x \in \partial S$. How do I proceed?

Comment: If $y \in V$, we have $f^{-1}(V) = U \cap S$ for some $U \in \tau$, so $\phi^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V) \cup S^c = (U \cap S) \cup S^c = U \cup S^c$ and...